# flot - plot color change if exceeds value

Tags: javascript, flot

Is it possible to change the color of a plotted line if that value exceeds a threshold ?

For example, if I have a maximum temperature of say 20 degrees, and any plotted value is higher than this, can the plot point and line's color be change to for example red ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Threshold plugin: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/threshold/index.html